# How can I select some specifc paths?

Tags: relays, exit-relays, circuit, guard-node

I want to select some specific routers as my entry relay, middle relay and exit node. I know I can edit torrc to determine entry and exit, how can I determine the middle one?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Knowing what you're trying to achieve often helps us know better how to answer.

Answer (score 1):

Tor offers no possibility to choose a specific middle node. The Tor software itself chooses at least this relay. This is because if someone could select specific routes through the network, it might hurt your anonymity.

Comment: Thank you. In Tor, the client (OP) selects relays to build circuit. Even if the client chooses the middle node, no attackers will know the path. It may be still anonymous. I see that some people use Stem to communicate with Tor Control Port to select path, but I don't know how to fulfil it.